# Kubernetes minion not completely connecting

Tags: docker, coreos, kubernetes, etcd, flannel

I have a dev kubernetes cluster setup where I have a minion running kube-proxy and kubelet. Both only start if it can connect to the master's apiserver, which it can.  Howerver I am getting

`error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "10.211.55.126": minion "10.211.55.126" not found`

I notice prior to that I get this: `Server rejected event '&api.Event` followed by a large json object with mostly empty string values.

repeatedly when I try running the minion's kubelet.  I have it pointing to a private ip and it is reporting that it can't fin the public ip.  I imagine this is an etcd issue but I'm not sure, also it maybe flanneld?

**Update 1**
I managed getting pass the initial error by registering the minion(node?) with the master.  This allow it to receive pods from mast and run the containers,; however, the minion is still not fully connected and resulting in the master to continuously push more pods to the minion.  The kubelet process is reporting: `Cannot get host IP: Host IP unknown; known addresses: []`. Is there a flag to run kubelet with to give it the host ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I have to manually register the minion prior to spinning up the minion instance.  This is because there is an open issue as of right now not allowing the minion to self-register in certain cases.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm using kube-register to register each minion/node on start of the kubelet service.